# React Js: Not able to reset nested state

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I am not able to reset the state in react

example

```
let initialState = {a:1, b:{c: 2, d: 4}, e:{f:6, g:7}}

constructor(){
this.state = initialState;
this.baseState = this.state;//set the initial state in the base state
}
```

//then suppose i modify the sate to e.f: 10 and b.c.:10; //state updated

//then i again try to reset the state to is initial by

```
this.setSate({...this.baseSate});
```

It modifies the elements that are not nested ie it will modify element 'a' but not the nested element 'b.c'

Comment: Hi Niks, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use functional `setState`,

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   ...this.baseState
}), () => console.log(this.state, this.baseState));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r7nvnq)

Comment: What I found out was, I was basically  importing the initial state from a different file,
so what is actually happening is while is do 'this.state = initialState' it copies the data as well as the address locations, and update the data in both state and the initialstate object

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is you are setting the reference of `this.state` to `this.baseState`.
So any changes you make to state are essentially also reflected in base state as both have the same reference i.e both refer to the same memory space in memory.

The below code should solve your problem.

```
let initialState = {a:1, b:{c: 2, d: 4}, e:{f:6, g:7}}

constructor(){
this.state = {...initialState};
this.baseState = {...this.state};//set the initial state in the base state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use deep coping the object

```
let initialState = {a:1, b:{c: 2, d: 4}, e:{f:6, g:7}}

constructor(){
this.state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState));
this.baseState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState));//set the initial state in the base state
}
```

[Reference Link](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript)